# Is my FC for regular rc planes or for drones with multiple props?

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, ardupilot

recently I decided to build a drone. While I'm learning everything I picked a FC. While researching about the FC I'm not sure if I picked the right one.

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2023-New-20X20mm-MATEK-H743-WLITE_1600761573416.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_title.4f695995q9B3Ya

[image]

Can I use this FC for a quadcopter?
What are the differences of FC's between plane and drone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Controller is just for planes. On the Schematic Wiring Picture on the manufacturing-website you can see the wiring to the motors. Here are just two S-Pins for motorcontrol.
[image]

http://www.mateksys.com/?portfolio=h743-wlite#tab-id-4

For a quadcopter you need 4 S-Pins to control every single motor separate.